# What name am I supposed to use for this com_error?

Tags: outlook, win32com

I am working with Python 3.7.9 through Anaconda on Windows 10 64-bit, pywin32 version 227. I want to find out which Outlook calendars in a given group I have permissions to read. I have tried pythoncom and pywintypes, all kinds of permutations of the "except" phrase. Basically, the simplest version should work:

```
    def toeIn(cal):
        Recurs=None
        for i, c in enumerate(readIterCal(cal))[0]:
            try:
                Recurs=c.IsRecurring
            except:
                pass
           
        return Recurs
```

Absolutely nothing prevents the code from breaking and throwing this error:
`com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (4096, 'Microsoft Outlook', "You don't have appropriate permission to perform this operation.", None, 0, -2147024891), None)`

"pythoncom.com_error": fail. "com_error": fail. "pywintypes.com_error": fail. As above: ANY exception: fail.

The error I'm getting is the answer to my question: no permission. Great! I just need to handle the error, store some response, move on. But it's a magical Microsoft error, apparently? Is there some way to slay the dragon, or is it just a cursed operation that shall not pass?